# Why not show Admob ads in my app after I generated sign apk.It is showed when I tested sample App id and sample App unit Id

Tags: admob, ads

My admob ads not showing in  my app.But when I test sample app unit id and app id,it is showed as a sample test id.

Comment: You should not run your app with live AdMob ad-IDs, Always use the test ad ID's. if the test ad ids are showing test ads, then you don't have to worry. Newly registered apps and newly created ad units typically take up to an hour to activate.

Because of this, you may not see live impressions immediately. check this https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en

Comment: thanks,I always tested sample id and I changed real id before generate apk.